# AAD Domain Services VM into AAD

Tags: entra-id, entra-domain-services

I have a cloud only environment. Virtual machines are connected via AAD Domain Services. How can I register these VMs in Azure AD. I would like to mount them in Intune.

thank you Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done unfortunately, the sync is one way only from (AAD) to (AAD DS), it doesn't sync backward whatever you do on (AAD DS) to (AAD).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview#how-does-azure-ad-ds-work